# Why does new clutch have much lower biting point?

Tags: clutch, hyundai, coupe

Car is hyundai coupe 2006.  When I bought this car it had a very high clutch biting point.  I have checked with other owners and they have confirmed hyundai coupes come with high clutch biting points.

I have recently changed clutch however it now has a low biting point like most cars.  The clutch was an aftermarket imitation(Exedy brand) rather than the original hyundai clutch.

What is the cause of the lower biting point, it is the aftermarket clutch or something the mechanic did?
Could it cause any problems for not being a high clutch as it should be by default?

Answer (score 3):

A new clutch is obviously still thicker than a used one, so it'll (dis)engage later in some cases/designs. (when the pedal's almost pressed fully) A different aftermarket clutch press will also make a difference if its design is different. And that's the case most of the time.

Some cars do have an adjustable clutch, and you can screw a special kind of nut to adjust the point of engaging. Yours might have that too. If not, as long as you can take off with screeching tyres, you very likely have sufficient clutch control at your disposal, and it'll just be a matter of getting familiar with it.